# Databricks CLI, terminate cluster

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-cli

I'm reviewing Databricks CLI [documentation](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/dev-tools/databricks-cli.html#clusters-cli) and cannot find a way to use CLI to terminate the cluster. There are instructions to create, delete, start, etc. but nothing about terminating. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: You're right, there doesn't seem to be anything for the CLI to terminate. The REST API looks like it may, though - https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/api/latest/clusters.html#delete-terminate

Answer (score 2):

In Azure Databricks CLI - when you run "**databricks clusters delete**" cmdlet, it terminates the cluster and after 30 days it will be permanently deleted.

[image]

Terminate a Spark cluster given its ID. The cluster is removed asynchronously. Once the termination has completed, the cluster will be in a TERMINATED state. If the cluster is already in a TERMINATING or TERMINATED state, nothing will happen.

**Note:** 30 days after a cluster is terminated, it is permanently deleted.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that this only deletes the cluster (after 30 days) **if** the cluster isn't pinned. Given that unpinned clusters are deleted after 30 days anyway, this `delete` is exactly what you want.